# What is the use of Android static inner activity class and where exactly we can use?

Tags: android

I have created a Activity called `MainActivity` Which extends from `ThirdActivity`. 
Next, I have an inner static activity called `AnotherActivity` which extends from `SecondActivity`. Below is my code:
1)MainActivity: which is the first activity that calls at first when app loads.

```
public class MainActivity extends ThirdActivity {

    public static class AnotherActivity extends SecondActivity{

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("Main Activity");
    }
}
```

2) ThirdActivty Code follows:

```
public abstract class ThirdActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        System.out.println("Third Activity");
    }
}
```

3) Inner static activity extended from  SecondActivity which consists of:

```
public abstract class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        System.out.println("Second Activity");
    }
}
```

Now the output of the above android program is:

```
Third Activity
MainActivity
```

In order to access the inner activities  we need to do declare in manifest as:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity$AnotherActivity" ></activity>
```

So, My question goes like this:

1) How to access Static inner Activity classes. 
2) When to use this scenario.?
3) Will the inner activity runs the life cycle process and what happens to already running MainActivity?

Comment: If you don't use the code, or don't know how to use it. Why don't you just delete it?

Comment: I don't think this is something that will work for Android.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Gvs: As a developer i feel we should aware of various things around technology. Please do comment only when you want to solve or already you aware of anwser rather using fair language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love answering bizarre questions before having coffee.

> 1) How to access Static inner Activity classes

What do you mean by "access"?  The fact that this is a static inner class is pretty much irrelevant.  It will run like an normal Activity.  When it is running, its `onCreate` method, e.g., will be called.  When that happens, there is a reference to the running instance of `AnotherActivity` in the canonical variable `this`.

> 2) When to use this scenario.

I can't think of a single reason.  In fact, I can think of a million reasons not to use it.  Ever.

> 3) Will the inner activity runs the life cycle process and what
>   happens to already running MainActivity?

Yes.  The "inner" activity will run through a normal Activity lifecycle.  Nothing happens to the `MainActivity` because it is not running when the `AnotherActivity` is running.  When `AnotherActivity` is started, `MainActivity` is stopped (`onPause`, maybe `onStop`, etc).

Comment: I'm very keen on your 3) answer.
If it runs the AnotherActivty and its life-cycle. then i should have to get the output as : ThirdActivity, MainActivity and SecondActivity. But, i didn't see anything like that. So, when it will start.? Will we need to explicitly start this.?

Comment: No!  You've never started AnotherActivity.  You started MainActivity.  The string of calls to super.onCreate cause the printout you see.  If you start AnotherActivity, MainActivity will be stopped, and you will then see "SecondActivity" (and nothing else), printed to the console as AnotherActivity's onCreate is called.